# Как ограничить запись вывода конкретной ошибки в скрипте

Tags: python-3.x, mysql, linux, bash

Извините за невежество, возможно вопрос простой.
часть баш скрипта

```
mysqldump -u user -ppsw name > /home/jung/dump/upperdeck_sql_dump_$time_temp.sql
/home/jung/scripts/debug_users.py
/home/jung/for_server/1.py 2>&1
sudo find /home/jung/dump/ -type f -mtime +5 -name '*.sql' -delete
```

Есть место с дампа. Который спамит в логи такую надпись

```
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

хотелось бы исключить эту надпись.
Что придумал.
в some_command добавить все строчки. Но выглядит крайне некрасиво.

```
output=$(some_command)

if [[ $output == *"mysqldump: [Warning]"* ]]; then
  filtered_output=$(echo "$output" | sed '/mysqldump: \[Warning\]/d')
  echo "$filtered_output" >> log.txt
else
  echo "$output" >> log.txt
fi
```

Через rsyslog пишется, несколько иная информация. Хотелось бы разрешить это в теле самого скрипта.

Comment: `mysqldump -u user -ppsw name | grep -v 'Using a password' > /home/jung/dump/upperdeck_sql_dump_$time_temp.sql` Здесь `grep -v` исключает строки, удовлетворяющие регулярному выражению

Comment: Может, что-то я делаю не так. Но продолжает писать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте пароль через переменную и ворнинг уйдет:

```
MYSQL_PWD='psw' mysqldump -u user name > /home/jung/dump/upperdeck_sql_dump_$time_temp.sql
```

Или через файл сонфигурации:

```
mysqldump -u user --defaults-file=/путь/к/файлу > /home/jung/dump/upperdeck_sql_dump_$time_temp.sql
```

Формат файла:

```
[mysqldump]
password=psd
```

Разрешения на файл должны быть 600

Comment: Он теперь вместо дампа самого SQL пишет  текстовик:
```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

Comment: Вроде работает, на тестовом образце." Продакшен" смогу глянуть только в понедельник. Тогда и отпишусь.

Comment: Да, все работает спасибо.